# Couchbase cluster - exception when 1 node is down

Tags: java, couchbase

I have a Couchbase cluster with 3 nodes. I have a java process that writes to this cluster.
When one of the nodes is down I'm getting this exception:

```
2013-12-30 14:03:23.259 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Node expected to receive data is inactive. This could be due to a failure within the cluster. Will check for updated configuration. Key without a configured node is: 980d330b2a96656a93bd08e48e6fc759135e6e6f.
Dec 30, 2013 2:03:23 PM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnectionFactory resubConfigUpdate
INFO: Attempting to resubscribe for cluster config updates.
Dec 30, 2013 2:03:23 PM com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnectionFactory$Resubscriber run
INFO: Reconnect attempt 1, waiting 0ms
2013-12-30 14:03:24.020 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=10.223.224.79/10.223.224.79:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2013-12-30 14:03:24.261 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Operation canceled because authentication or reconnection and authentication has taken more than one second to complete.
2013-12-30 14:03:24.263 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Node expected to receive data is inactive. This could be due to a failure within the cluster. Will check for updated configuration. Key without a configured node is: 980d330b2a96656a93bd08e48e6fc759135e6e6f.
2013-12-30 14:03:25.265 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Operation canceled because authentication or reconnection and authentication has taken more than one second to complete.
441016302 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR com.polimo.rtb.writer.CouchbaseWriter  - Error while trying to write to couchbase
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Cancelled
        at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:176)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.mutateWithDefault(MemcachedClient.java:1842)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.incr(MemcachedClient.java:1788)
        at com.polimo.rtb.writer.CouchbaseWriter.incrementCounterInDb(CouchbaseWriter.java:107)
        at com.polimo.rtb.writer.CouchbaseWriter.write(CouchbaseWriter.java:90)
        at com.polimo.rtb.consumer.ConsumerThread.run(ConsumerThread.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I'm using a [standard java client](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/java/getting-started) and with the described behavior I feel I'm missing the whole point of using a cluster, I mean, if one node is down everything should be working still.

Is there some configuration I'm missing (server or client)?

Comment: What replication options do you have - if you don't have replicas enabled then loosing one node would mean that the data on that node is no longer available and hence you wouldn't be able to increment that document.

Comment: Also - could you post an extract of your code please?

Comment: @DaveRigby is correct, if a node fails, you either have to fail it over to replica partitions (either automatic or manual), or if you don't have replicas configured, then the keys that hash into the partitions that live on the failed node will be inaccessible.

Comment: @DaveRigby Which replication options should I follow? Should I find it in the Cluster Manager?

Comment: @forhas: Replication is set on a per-bucket basis - see http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#creating-and-editing-data-buckets for details.

Comment: @DaveRigby This indeed seems a configuration issue in the server side as you pointed out. The links you posted helped get it right, feel free to post it as an answer (I'll add my comments if required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication is configured on a per-bucket basis. If no replicas are configured then when a node goes down the vBucket(s) hosted by that node will be no longer be available, and hence any attempt to perform operations on that data fail as you saw.

See the [Creating and Editing Data Buckets](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#creating-and-editing-data-buckets) in the Couchbase Manual for details on configuring replicas (specifically the Replicas section of the "Create Bucket" process and the [Failover](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#couchbase-admin-tasks-failover) Nodes section).

Comment: I have enable replica for my bucket with 2 node, but i am getting same error got while using  `client.getBulk(keys)`. It works fine for `client.get(key)` method.

Answer (score 0):

How is your client configured. Do you have in the configuration all cluster nodes IP addresses? If you have only one IP address in your configuration and this node crash your cluster is not accessible for your application.